# Find out peak memory usage of a container spawned by kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to find out the peak memory usage of a container that was launched by kubernetes? (Without polling, since that can miss memory spikes.)

From other similar questions on this site: GNU time and [cgmemtime](https://github.com/gsauthof/cgmemtime) can get the high water mark without polling, but they have to start the process/container.

This would greatly help inform setting memory requests/limits.

Comment: Hi \`Yang\` if containers have their sys logs stored in a persistent volume there might be a way but all the container volumes are ephemeral by default so, if you want to get peak memory usage stats you should have the container running, if you want to get these stats of a exited container you can use some monitoring tools and find the trend.